# How to upload Scrapy data to FTP

Tags: scrapy

I try to upload scv to ftp. How I see where are 2 ways: FEED_FORMAT + FEED_URI and FEEDS.

My settings.py with first way connecting to FTP but doesn't upload file. I get error 550. And also it's deprecated.

```
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
FEED_URI = 'ftp://***/files/file.csv'
```

So I try to use FEEDS. I read this https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEEDS a many times and searched examples here and asks at official Discord with no answer. This part is works and create file:

```
FEEDS = {
 pathlib.Path('file.csv'): {
    'format': 'csv',
  }
}
```

I need to write FTP login and pass for FEEDS but I don't know how. I tried this and it's doesn't work:

```
FEED_STORAGES = {
 'ftp': 'ftp://****/files/file.csv',
}
```

I tried something like this and it's doesn't work too:

```
FEEDS = {
  pathlib.Path('file.csv'): {
    'format': 'csv',
  }
 'ftp': 'ftp://****/files/file.csv',
}
```

I think it's a quite simple question because got answers like "read the doc" but I'm stuck here.

So first question can I write login and pass in settings.py? Or maybe after deprecated FEED_FORMAT and FEED_URI it's should be in another file.

And second question how to write login and pass to FTP for FEEDS. I realy need syntax here not link for this docs https://docs.scrapy.org/ because I read it all. If question in fact
is realy hard I would appreciate for link to another docs which not copypaste official.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get error 550.

From what I can tell, that error means the path you're trying to use doesn't exist, or you don't have the permissions to access it.
I would recommend checking the path and/or your credentials.

But keep reading if you want to try using `FEEDS` instead.

The docs do show an example of what you want: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feeds

But to simplify that code even more, a minimal example would be something like:

```py
FEEDS = {
    'ftp://****/files/file.csv': {
        'format': 'csv',
    },
}
```

Of course, you can add additional options if you want to modify the defaults.

Comment: Thank you so much!